# Can't run pip from virtualenv - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python3, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm trying to use pip to install various requirements in my virtualenv, but I can't get around the error `Segementation fault (core dumped)`. That error seems to indicate memory access problems, but I don't understand how or why that would happen in a venv.

```
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~/Documents/eroi-erp$ pipenv --python 3.7.2
Warning: Python 3.7.2 was not found on your system…
Would you like us to install CPython 3.7.2 with pyenv? [Y/n]: Y
Error: invalid input
Would you like us to install CPython 3.7.2 with pyenv? [Y/n]: Y
Installing CPython 3.7.2 with pyenv (this may take a few minutes)…
✔ Success! 
Downloading Python-3.7.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.2...
Installed Python-3.7.2 to /home/soverton/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2


Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /home/soverton/Pipfile
Using /home/soverton/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7m (3.7.2) to create virtualenv…
⠧ Creating virtual environment...Using base prefix '/home/soverton/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2'
Overwriting /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/lib/python3.7/orig-prefix.txt with new content
New python executable in /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/bin/python3.7m
Not overwriting existing python script /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/bin/python (you must use /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/bin/python3.7m)
Command /home/soverton/.loca...ZmsRb/bin/python3.7m -m pip config list had error code -11
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/soverton/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7m
✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~/Documents/eroi-erp$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
 . /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/bin/activate
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$  . /home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/bin/activate
(soverton) soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~/Documents/eroi-erp$ pip install django
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(soverton) soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~/Documents/eroi-erp$ pip
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(soverton) soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~/Documents/eroi-erp$ pip3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the pip that you intend to run? try to issue the command: which pip.

Comment: It looks like it's running pip from the venv: `(soverton) soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~/Documents/eroi-erp$ which pip
/home/soverton/.local/share/virtualenvs/soverton-mUoZmsRb/bin/pip`

Comment: Also, I confirmed that user soverton has read-write permissions on that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by first creating an environment using Python 3.6: `pipenv --python 3.6`. In this environment, both `pip` and `pip3` worked. I then exited this environment, deleted both `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` and then created another environment using `pipenv --python 3.7.2` in the same directory and both `pip` and `pip3` worked again.

I guess it must be an issue with Python 3.7.2?

*Edit:*

As Shaun mentioned below, it could be to do with `anaconda` being installed alongside vanilla Python and removing `anaconda` fixed it.

Comment: My issue was Anaconda. Once I removed Anaconda from the system, I was able to start cleaning up the problems with Python and virtualenvs.

Comment: I also have anaconda installed! Seems to still work though :)

Answer (score 0):

first find out the location of pip.

run `which pip`

The output will points to a file. just rename the file with extension `.py`
That's it